# Select newest single field of a combined SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have the following table in SQL Server 2019.

- The row with the highest `id` is the newest row.
- Column `obj_id` has an immutable identifier for an object.
- Column `obj_name` has the name of the object at the time the row was added.

| id | obj_name | obj_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | now1 | 1 |
| 1 | prev-prev1 | 1 |
| 6 | now2 | 2 |
| 4 | prev1 | 1 |
| 3 | prev2 | 2 |
| 2 | prev-prev2 | 2 |

What I need is the most recent `object_name`.

| obj_name |
| --- |
| now1 |
| now2 |

I tried many things, to no avail. One of my ideas was to do the following

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    [obj_name]
FROM
    [Table]
ORDER BY 
    [id] DESC
```

which failed with this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

What is an efficient way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows per obj_id in desc id order, and then pick the first such row(s)

```
select obj_name
from (
  select id, obj_name, obj_id
      , row_number() over (partition by obj_id order by id desc) as rn
  from test
) as t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Window functions are your friend for this kind of problem. `ROW_NUMBER()` is the classic solution, as per Lennart's answer. Generally it is more performant than the answer I'm about to provide, when you have multiple fields that you want to get the latest value of, since it's only a single window function call as opposed to multiple.

But you only care about a single field in this case, so it shouldn't be much different performance-wise. Also if you prefer slightly less code by not needing to use a subquery or CTE, and performance is sufficient enough, it's good to be aware of the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) and [`LAST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window functions, which can be leveraged to solve your problem like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(obj_name) OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS obj_name
FROM [Table] -- Hopefully this isn't your actual table name
```

Comment: In the past I found that LAST_VALUE has a quirk where the ORDER BY is also used to partition the result set. If this is still true, you would need to add `RANGE/ROW BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` to get the result the op is looking for.

Comment: @GMassDBA Yea, I think it's actually by design but I forget in what cases that happens in (I thought something like when the field applied inside the function is also part of the `ORDER BY` clause). Unfortunately I don't have a way to test at the moment, so I updated my code to the other alternative to safeguard this, which is using `FIRST_VALUE()` and `ORDER BY ... DESC`.

Comment: I also think it's by design. The default range for a window function over an ordered window is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Despite counter intuitive in the case of LAST_VALUE, it would also be a bit odd if those functions used another default window.

Comment: FWIW, I did a small comparision:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6f10e5874c3b983874880f0560359951  Postgres seems to reuse the window frame for several first_value functions, but the additional filter rn = 1 appears to speed things up anyhow.

Comment: @Lennart Interesting, I wonder if SQL Server has the same optimization built into its window functions.  I've definitely seen a slowdown with more window functions (even over the same window frame) in some cases, but never enough to make me care to investigate it lol.